# Time dependent perturbation, particle on a segment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, perturbation-theory

Consider a particle of mass $M$ moving alongside a segment of length $a$.
Wavefunction:
$$\psi_n(x)=\sqrt\frac{2}{a} \sin(\frac{n\pi}{a}x)$$
Energy:
$$E_n=\frac{\hbar^2\pi^2 n^2}{2Ma^2}$$
Time-dependent perturbation:
$$\varepsilon(t)=\varepsilon_0e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}.$$
Particle is in a ground state $n = 1$. What is the probability to find the system  in state $n = 4$?
This formula:
$$p_{m\leftarrow n}=\frac{1}{\hbar^2} \left| \int_0^t e^{i\omega_{mn}t}V_{mn}(t)\,dt \right|^2, m\neq n$$
$$V_{mn}=\int_0^a \psi_m^*\varepsilon (t) \psi_n \, dx.$$

Okay, I try to compute $V_{m1}$:

$$V_{m1}=\int_0^a \frac{2}{a}\varepsilon_0 e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} \sin(\frac{m\pi}{a}x) \sin(\frac{\pi}{a}x) \,dx = \frac{2}{a}\varepsilon_0 e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} \int_0^a  \sin(\frac{m\pi}{a}x) \sin(\frac{\pi}{a}x) \,dx = 0$$

Right off I find this integral to be equal to zero. Am I doing anything wrong? Or is the answer zero?

Answer (score 0):

Your perturbation is constant in space, so that any integral of the type
$$
V_{nm}=\epsilon \int_0^a dx\, \psi_m(x)\psi_n(x)=0 
$$
by orthogonality of the wavefunctions.

There are two possibilities.

1. there’s a typo and $\epsilon(t)$ depends on $x$ somehow,
2. it’s a trick question.

Comment: Alright, $\varepsilon$ stands for electric field. I must have multiplied it by $x$ I guess...

Comment: can you edit the question to properly reflect any update or change?